# Why is it so difficult to link SPDK libraries?

Tags: dpdk

I am trying to build a simple application that calls a simple status checking SPDK API. However, I am struggling to resolve all the dependencies to do this.

Here is what I did so far:

Attempt 1. Build SPDK from scratch and link shared SPDK libraries.

Result 1. Long list of "spdk_*" shared libraries. Difficult to understand which ones to link.

Attempt 2. Reading from their website, link the code with `-lspdk -lspdk_env_dpdk -ldpdk`.

Result 2. `libdpdk.so` not found.

Attempt 3. Suspecting `spdk/dpdk` not being properly built, rebuild/install SPDK with various configure flags `--with-dpdk`.

Result 3. Still `libdpdk.so` not found.

Attempt 4. Getting tired of this non-sense, just tried with `apt install libdpdk-dev`.

Result 4. Still `libdpdk.so` not found.

Here are my questions.

1. What am I doing wrong? Should I be linking `librte_*` (which are related to DPDK and main reason why compiler complains) manually?
2. Why is SPDK and DPDK integrated so poorly designed? Why must they be separate with such a huge dependency mess (e.g., `spdk_env_dpdk`?)
3. How can I avoid such things from happening when engineering my own library?

Comment: Install pkg-config ?spdk Use pkg-config to discover libdpdk